# SQL JOIN with And Clause with some some condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL Query :

```
SELECT run.RN_CYCLE_ID ,test.[TS_EXEC_STATUS] , count(test.[TS_EXEC_STATUS]) 
FROM [td].[TEST] test 
INNER JOIN [td].[RUN] run 
ON test.TS_TEST_ID = run.RN_TEST_ID
 And run.RN_TEST_ID IN   
     (SELECT DISTINCT rn_test_id FROM [td].[RUN] WHERE [RN_CYCLE_ID] IN (12973 , 13794) )
GROUP BY  test.[TS_EXEC_STATUS] , run.RN_CYCLE_ID  order by run.RN_CYCLE_ID;
```

This is showing the data not just for RN_CYCLE_ID - 12973 And 13794.

But also for some of other RN_CYCLE_ID.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Might be wrong, but shouldnt your AND run.RN_TEST_ID IN actually be WHERE run.RN_TEST_ID IN ??

Comment: @Mike tried the same query with WHERE condition also instead of AND but still the result was same :(

Comment: i got the problem -: run.RN_TEST_ID IN  (SELECT DISTINCT rn_test_id FROM [td].[RUN] WHERE [RN_CYCLE_ID] IN (12973 , 13794))
the Run and Test Tables had One to Many relationship so the same test.RN_TEST_ID was present in more than one run.[RN_CYCLE_ID]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT run.RN_CYCLE_ID ,test.[TS_EXEC_STATUS] , count(test.[TS_EXEC_STATUS]) 
FROM [td].[TEST] test 
    INNER JOIN [td].[RUN] run 
    ON test.TS_TEST_ID = run.RN_TEST_ID
WHERE run.[RN_CYCLE_ID] IN (12973 , 13794) 
GROUP BY  test.[TS_EXEC_STATUS] , run.RN_CYCLE_ID  
order by run.RN_CYCLE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

@br001 : 
Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow,

If you tried using `where` instead of `And` and it too didn't work then I would say you should break down your query and check at every level.
Steps you can do :

1) Remove `group by` and `order by` - and check the result.

2) Check if `inner query` is giving correct result or not - check

```
SELECT DISTINCT rn_test_id FROM [td].[RUN] WHERE [RN_CYCLE_ID] IN (12973 , 13794)
```

3) Check with only one condition - that is, check `[RN_CYCLE_ID]  = 12973` or `[RN_CYCLE_ID] = 13794` and check the result.

4) Also, at every step check that you don't have any corrupted data.

Else, I guess query is correct.(at least I don't see any mistake)